# How to keep an empty slice area in highcharts after clicking on legendItem

Tags: charts, highcharts

In this example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-legend

label click, sliced the part of pie chart. I need to set visible to clicked pie chart part, but when I use setVisible function I have default behavior back unless i have return false, ex.

```
       pie: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        legendItemClick: function (event) {
                            var visibility = this.visible;

                            this.setVisible(!visibility);

                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
```

Comment: How do you want it to work? Not removing the slice, just leaving an open space?

Comment: Can you clarify what the desired behavior is? In the fiddle you linked to, clicking the legend item toggles visibility, which is what your question sounds like you're asking for.

Comment: Yeah, I want to set just an open space

Comment: return false does not change anything when I use setVisible(),

It still work like a default state

Comment: Kindly check the stackoverflow answer above. It has what you need.. it's a duplicate question

Comment: I have seen this example, but I need something else, that example just disable default behavior on label click, I need to disable and toggle visibility, I need to leave empty space on that part of pie chart

Comment: for example, I have 30% red, 70% green, when I have click on 70% label my green part disapear and have 100% red, I need to save state to red (30%). Make sense ?

Comment: try to click on labels and you will see chnage it or not
http://jsfiddle.net/3vVGB/22/

Comment: "return false" cancels the default action, but setting the visibility the way that you are *IS* the default action. So you're telling the chart not to do the default, then telling it to do the default. Not sure how to achieve what you want, but toggling visibility will not work for you. Perhaps setting a fill color of 'transparent'?

Comment: Your question title is misleading.. Change it to "How to keep an empty slice area in highcharts after clicking on legendItem". That's why everyone was confused.

Comment: Can I set hidden visibility to path element, not to g, without updating function ?, I mean to set style attribute or something like that, because for transparent fill color I need to keep the previus color (second click on pie chart label will set previus color).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `ignoreHiddenPoint` option set to `false` to leave the slice area open after deactivating it in the legend.

Sample code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pj0cfsb/)):

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        ignoreHiddenPoint: false
    }
}
```

Comment: wasn't aware of that property. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you:

```
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                    var colors = this.series.chart.options.colors;
                    var newColor = (
                        this.color == 'transparent' 
                        ? colors[this.index] 
                        : 'transparent'
                    );
                    this.update({color:newColor});
                    return false; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

On legend item click, it updates the point's color to 'transparent'.

example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/g15uduwu/

**[[edited with updated code to account for returning to original color]]**

Comment: this actually works, but I have checkbox with pie chart, which have gray background when i click on the lable and hide the clicked part. Cahnging the chart color also change the checkbox color, thats why I don't want to change the color )))

Comment: If you can post a fiddle of that functionality, we can see what we can do about that as well.

Comment: nevermind, Ondkloss's answer is better :), wasn't aware of that property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch a legendItemClick and customise action, returning FALSE in the event.

```
legendItemClick: function () {
                            var point = this,
                                vis;

                            point.visible = point.options.visible = vis = vis === UNDEFINED ? !point.visible : vis;
                             this.series.chart.legend.colorizeItem(point, vis);

                            if(vis) {
                                point.graphic.attr({
                                    opacity:1
                                });
                                point.dataLabel.show();
                                point.connector.show();
                            } else {
                                point.graphic.attr({
                                    opacity:0
                                });
                                point.dataLabel.hide();
                                point.connector.hide();
                            }

                            return false;
                        }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/x65f5qaz/1/

Comment: yeah, this is other way, but the small and optimal version we already have )))). Thanks for replying..

Comment: Right, it only a workaround, if you would like to add more options / features.